# Replace string resources from AAR library

Tags: android, translation, aar

In my app, I have added an external library (AAR) and it's not translated to all languages that my own app is, so I am looking to manually translate missing strings. My plan is to add them to the app's strings.xml, overriding string ID's that the library uses.

However, it seems the library only takes English translation, not, for example, German when the phone has German language set, as in the example below:

[image]

Here is a tooltip showing me that German will be used from my strings.xml:

[image]

Please note that other strings, which are not from AAR library, are showing properly translated (in this case in German on a German phone).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that in the library they are forcing English, by overriding the language of the android Context that they use. You're gonna have to check their source-code to see if that's the case, and if it is, you're probably out of luck without forking the library and modifying it.